# How to detect when Harshen's jQuery-countdownTimer reaches 00:00

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm integrating [Harshen Panday's countdownTimer plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/countdowntimer), but I want to print `hello` when it reaches `00:00`. Is there any way I can get notified of that event?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#ms_timer').countdowntimer({
    minutes: 03,
    seconds: 00,
    size: "lg"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/jquery.countdownTimer.min.js"></script>

<span id="ms_timer" class="d-block mb-2"></span>
<h3 id="getTime" class="mb-3 text-uppercase"><b>Book Consultation</b></h3>
<h5 id="getPrice"><b class="strike">RS. 500</b></h5>
<h2 class="mb-0"><b>RS. 300</b></h2>
```

Comment: @trincot you're right, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation gives [timeUp](https://github.com/harshen/jQuery-countdownTimer#timeup):

> **timeUp**
>
> - Type: `Function`
> - Default: `null`
> - The name of the callback function that is invoked when the countdown reaches zero. Within the function `this` refers to the division that holds the widget. No parameters are passed in. Provide the name to this option without quotes.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#ms_timer').countdowntimer({
    minutes: 00,
    seconds: 05,
    size: "lg",
    timeUp: () => console.log("Hello")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/jquery.countdownTimer.min.js"></script>
<span id="ms_timer" class="d-block mb-2"></span>
<h3 id="getTime" class="mb-3 text-uppercase"><b>Book Consultation</b></h3>
<h5 id="getPrice"><b class="strike">RS. 500</b></h5>
<h2 class="mb-0"><b>RS. 300</b></h2>
```

Comment: if I want to perform a event at the place of `console.log('Hello')` will it possible?

Comment: Yes. You can put any function reference there, like `timeUp: myFunction`, and it will be called.